# Unable to compile project with MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: c++, qt, mongodb, compilation, database-connection

I've downloaded the sources for C++ MongoDB driver from this URL: http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/cxx-driver and compiled it on Windows (with some changes in Scons script) to "mongoclient.lib".

What I needed to have during compilation are the paths to:

- include files from Visual Studio (2010 here)
- include files from "Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4" - downloaded from MS site as ISO image
- Boost libraries (i used 1.47)

Now I'd like to make use of that library in Qt console application but all I get are thousands of errors (most of them look like I used the wrong platform SDK). 
I've uploaded those compilation errors to pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/cUnKYdGg

The questions is simple: What am I missing in order to have the project compiling without errors? Should some other platform SDK be used? Or some paths are set incorrectly in the project maybe?

My .pro file looks like the one below:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2012-06-01T21:20:08
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = QtConsoleApp
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "e:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_47/"
INCLUDEPATH += "d:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "d:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "e:/temp/proj/QtConsoleApp/libs/src/mongo/"
INCLUDEPATH += "e:/temp/proj/QtConsoleApp/libs/src/"
INCLUDEPATH += "e:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_47/lib/"
LIBS += -L"e:/temp/proj/QtConsoleApp/libs/" -lmongoclient

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Comment: If anyone is downvoting my question, I'd be glad to see the reason why. Simply not to make any mistakes in the future.

Comment: These look like VC++ / Qt problems. Perhaps you could remove Mongo from the picture and get your project to build without it first. You aren't even getting to the linking step where your mongoclient.lib affects anything. If adding Mongo is what causes the problem, maybe you can provide before-and-after versions showing what worked without Mongo, and what you've changed.

Comment: Thank you @noa. Looks like a reasonable suggestion - I'll try this out too.